# How to set the background color of a data grid row using a viewmodel value and a lookup dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-style

I have a DataGrid where I set `ItemsSource` as such:

```
TheGrid.ItemsSource = items;
```

And a XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="TheGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style.Setters>
      <Setter Property = "Background" Value="{Binding = ???}" ></Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, in my view, I have a public dictionary as such:

```
public IDictionary<string, Color> IdColors { get; set; }
```

The issue is I do not know how to take the Id from my `ItemsSource` and pass it into the binding such that it would access the dictionary on that id and take the color.
I have read alternative solutions,such as:

1. Doing this in a converter
2. Subscribing to `LoadingRow` and just setting it there programmatically

I think I know how to do #2 but I've come to ask stack whether that would be advisable.

Comment: How many values does your dictionary contain?

Comment: The dictionary contains under 100 values

Comment: Using a converter as shown in the answer below would be the best option in that case. If you only had a couple of values (up to 10 maybe), a `DataTrigger` in the `Style` would be preferable.

Comment: I see,thank you.Converters are better for any heavy lifting then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define a converter, you can do it this way:

```cs
public class IdToBrushConverter : IValueConverter {
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an ID into a Brush
    /// </summary>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return new SolidColorBrush(IdColors[value]); //need for example some static access to IdColors here
        //You can also define IdColors here or use other custom logic.
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in your XAML, you can call the converter like this:

```xml
<DataGrid Name="TheGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False CanUserDeleteRows="False">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <!--You might need some namespace prefix here-->
    <view:IdToBrushConverter x:Key="IdToBrushConverter"></view:IdToBrushConverter>
    <Style.Setters>
      <Setter Property = "Background" Value="{Binding Path=Id, Converter={StaticResource IdToBrushConverter}" ></Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The converter will be called and applied to the `Id` property and return a `SolidColorBrush` with the color you want.

Comment: Making the `IdColors` prooperty `static` is not a good solution. Better use a `MultiBinding` instead to bind the `Background` to the `IdColors` property and to the `ID` property.

Comment: Thats actually what I went with @BionicCode.Took me a cuople hours of searching around to make it work, especially since I wrote a wrong name of my codebehind dictionary property in xaml